# How can I send an HTML message from Gmail?

Tags: gmail, html

HTML:

```
<p style="background-color:green; padding: 30px;">Hello</p>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Usually you can write that into an HTML file, render it, and copy the email from the browser into Gmail's compose pane.

Comment: What about <body style="backcolor:red;"></body> ?

Comment: @faressoft Use Thunderbird in that case.

Comment: Do you mean insert > HTML ? Noting changed when i put <body style="backcolor:red;"></body> in it !

Comment: I doubt any email program would let you do that. It's better to make a `<div>` and style that. Thought it could also be that you meant `bgcolor` and not `backcolor`...

Comment: +1 This works. To test simply open an email in Gmail itself. Preferably the one which is sent through some email client which has HTML enabled and has images in it. Select it's content. Copy. And paste it into the compose pane. Yes just make sure that you have Rich formatting selected in the compose options as shown by @Nigel

Comment: If you past HTML in the compose pain, you just see code. This isn't working

Comment: @Richard, you missed the "from the browser" part. Copy the rendered contents, not the HTML source.

Comment: This used to work for me, but it's not working for me now (April 2017). :(

Answer (score 9):

Google **does not** support this feature: ([***Source***](http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=8260))

> Please note that Gmail doesn't recognize HTML tags inserted in the body of a message

*However, it might be possible with an external 3 party application such as Outlook or ThunderBird*.

---

Outlook 2003 or earlier had option to send HTML via **File > Send > Page by Email**. However, Microsoft have *removed* this feature for *security* reasons in Outlook 2007 and 2010. Here is an [**article**](http://fuelyourcoding.com/outlook-2010-and-html-email/) that explains Microsoft's actions. There is a 'grass-roots effort' to get this feature added back Outlook. For more information about his movement visit [**FixOutlook.org**](http://fuelyourcoding.com/outlook-2010-and-html-email/).

Comment: thank you. Iam using Outlook but I don't know how can I send a html code. How can I do that ?

Comment: I don't use Outlook anymore so I am not completely sure. I did find [this](http://www.slipstick.com/mail1/html.htm) page with 4 methods to HTML emails.

Comment: @SgtOJ, I think your source is outdated.................

Answer (score 3):

I think you should use a client that lets you write HTML email and set it up to use your gmail account. I don't think you can do it from Gmail's web interface.

Sending HTML email with Outlook express and Thunderbird:
http://webdesign.about.com/od/intermediatetutorials/a/aa050800b.htm

Not sure how to directly input HTML in an email using outlook.

Answer (score 3):

Body is not an acceptable tag in gmail, and most email clients disregard backgrounds unless they're in divs.

There's a great resource on the subject of what email clients support and don't support called the [Email Standards Project](http://www.email-standards.org/).

As for entering html in gmail, you're going to have to do the copy paste thing that digitxp said, but don't include the html, head or body tags, just the content tags.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ctrlq.org/html-mail/](http://ctrlq.org/html-mail/) to send HTML emails.

Answer (score 1):

Gmail does not support HTML natively but it is possible to do so via [Chrome extensions](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/search/gmail%20html?_category=extensions).

I love this one: [Free HTML Editor for Gmail](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/free-html-editor-for-gmai/ioinaaeeacahcmbgfmeaaofhfkijpdeb).

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rich Test Formatting 1]

[image: Rich text formatting 2]
In gmail web client, the easiest way to click on **Rich formatting >>** that would open up the formating tools and select whatever formating your want instead of composing it somewhere else and pasting it.

Comment: How do I do a heading?